# Cannot format SD Card

Tags: macos, disk-utility, sd-card

I'm having trouble formatting this SD card. The write protect switch is off, of course. I tried using the built-in card reader on my MacBook Air and then a USB one. It won't even format on my Windows machine. It's hard to believe the card is bad as it was working just fine about a month ago when I last used it and I barely wrote data to it in its lifetime.

It doesn't mount automatically, nor does it show up in the Disk Utility GUI. However, diskutil on the command line sees it just fine.

[image]

When I try to format it through diskutil with the following command:

```
sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 NIKON MBRFormat /dev/disk3
```

It does not work and I get the following error message:

[image]

I'm just perplexed as it has been in a case and like I said above, I've barely used it. It's hard to believe it died while not being in a computer, but it wouldn't be the strangest thing I've experienced in my life on the computer.

It would be much appreciated if someone can help me revive the card, if possible.

Comment: USB flash drives/SD cards aren't worth fighting once they start to fail. Try to format it in multiple devices, including your camera. If no joy, discard. See http://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only for a comprehensive guide

Comment: You are also encouraged to see the questions in tag [tag:sd-card]